# how to call the rest() function the proper way

Tags: javascript, function, callback

The expected outcome of this logic is that
everytime i call the function rest()
the health of the creature should be restored to 10
When I try to call the function rest
i get a 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined

(I want to bind the function to the DOM that when the 'rest' image is clicked the function rest() is called and
the health of the creature restores)

```
 const creature = {
   name: 'apiGong',
   alive: true,
  inventory: [],
   health: 5,
  item: {type: "claws", damage: 1,
  },
 }


   function rest(creature){
    let health = creature.health
   while (health < 10){
    health++
  }
     return health;
   }
```

Comment: you need to show how you call it. It's sure that you pass `undefined` as an argument though.

Comment: Why don't you just do `creature.health=10`?